# Деструктор по умолчанию

Tags: c++, память

Допустим, есть класс:

```
class A
{
public:
private:
    std::string a;
    int b;
    bool c;
    UserClass d;
};
```

Для него был создан `std::shared_ptr`. При вызове `Sharedptr_classA.reset();` Будет ли вызван деструктор для `UserClass` и будет ли освобождена память из-под остальных свойств?

Comment: вы пробывали вставить cout в деструктор для проверки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, будет. Порядок такой - сначала вызовется деструктор `A`, потом - всех полей класса в порядке, обратном порядку их объявления.

Answer (score 1):

Деструктор будет вызван, если больше не останется ни одного указателя на данный объект. `shared_ptr` работает со счетчиком ссылок, и деструктор вызывается, когда этот счетчик обнуляется.

Comment: Да, предполагается, что это был последний shared_ptr. А как насчет остальных свойств?

Comment: @Dmitry Что вы имеете в виду? Не очень понимаю, о каких свойствах вы говорите? Или вы о членах типа ваших a,b,c,d? Естественно, что деструктор класса вызывает деструкторы для всех членов.

Comment: `std::string a;` ,`int b;`, `bool c;`

Comment: @Dmitry Деструктор класса вызывает деструкторы для всех членов.

Comment: @Dmitry Вот вам маленькая программка - набрасывайте такие и проверяйте, если в чем сомневаетесь: `class Quest
{
public:
    Quest() { cout << __func__ << endl; }
    ~Quest() { cout << __func__ << endl; }
};

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { cout << __func__ << endl; }
    ~Test() { cout << __func__ << endl; }
private:
    Quest q;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    shared_ptr<Test> t(new Test);
    t.reset();
    system("pause");
}`  Простите за отсутствие форматирования, но тут я ничего не могу сделать...